# Proving $ i^i $ value without euler's identity?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

I would really like to prove a value of  $ i^i$ without euler's identity, I just want to know if it is possible.

I have not seen a single proof that does not rely on it.

I had the idea of differentiating thr function $ f(z) = z^i $ and then integrating the result on the interval $[i, i+0.001] $ but nothing would give me the actual value in terms of $ \pi $

Does there exist some way to do this without eulers identity

Comment: You can't even define $i^i$ without Euler's identity.

Comment: When $a$ and $x$ are complex, what is your *definition* of $a^x$?

Comment: Indeed if you consider $f(z) = z^i$, then $f'(z) = \frac{i}{z} \cdot f(z)$. Also take the initial condition $f(1) = 1$. Solving this Cauchy problem in the complex domain will give you a determination for $z^i$.  It depends  how you go from $1$ to $i$ ( the homotopy type of the path). Best to take the path an arc of the unit circle. *Not* a silly question...

Comment: @orangeskid wouldn't you just get $ i^i $ instead of a specific value?

Comment: Another possible approach: write $I =(1+z)^2$, with $|z|< 1\ $ ( $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)-1$ ). Then one could consider $i^i = (1+z)^{2i}$ and the RHS is given by [Newton's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem). One sees that we get approximately $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: @jizert: you could integrate numerically, and get a numerical (approximate) value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your integral approach, but for $$\frac{\partial i^x}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2} i \pi  i^x$$ one has $$\int\limits_0^i \frac{1}{2} \pi  i^{x+1} \, dx+1=i^i$$ and for $$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x}=i x^{i-1}$$ one has $$\int\limits_0^i i x^{i-1} \, dx=i^i$$.

Comment: @Steven Clark: It's not the usual integral, rather solving a diff eqn ( a Cauchy problem).  There are many diff eqn that can only be solved numerically ( say using Euler's method, or others). One could try to solve this numerically and see what one gets...Note that we need a path... best to use the arc of circle from $1$ to $i$.